# Approximation/sampling of complex Likelihoods

Tags: references, likelihood

I would like to ask a quite vague question, in order to gather references and ideas about that topic.

My question is the following:

In cases where the computation of Likelihood in Bayesian framework is complex or computational inneficient, what other methods/approximations exist in order to either calculate/approximate the Likelihood or take samples from it.

Comment: Some relevant posts: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/221676/parameter-estimation-for-intractable-likelihoods-alternatives-to-approximate-b/222425#222425 https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/191492/how-does-saddlepoint-approximation-work/192380#192380 https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108048/abc-why-not-use-the-distance-measure-as-a-pseudo-likelihood-instead/108134#108134

Comment: ... and [this stored google search](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&client=ubuntu&hs=QHv&sxsrf=ALeKk03TZVhfPhHq5ElHwhxOUmtN9yvWtA%3A1608126155033&ei=yw7aX-HLAYHC5OUPhY2NiAc&q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fstats.stackexchange.com+likelihood+intractable&oq=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fstats.stackexchange.com+likelihood+intractable&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQA1DYgQJY4qwCYKSvAmgAcAB4AIABogGIAaYMkgEEMjIuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrAAQE&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwih3eXh0NLtAhUBIbkGHYVGA3EQ4dUDCAw&uact=5)

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/221676/7224, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/295634/7224, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/127180/7224

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main ways (that I am aware of) of dealing with this problem when the likelihood is difficult to work with.

The (probably) more popular method is Approximate Bayesian Computation. Suppose I have observed data $x$ and want to infer parameters $\theta$. The basic idea behind this is to generate samples from an appropriate probability distribution $x_{\text{synthetic}} \mid \theta \sim\text{model}(\theta)$. If $x_{\text{synthetic}}$ is ''close'' to $x$ retain $\theta$. [wikipedia page for ABC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_Bayesian_computation). This is okay if we can't write down the likelihood but can easily simulate from the model. (e.g. lots of predator-prey or birth-death type models).

An other method is to use a Gaussian Process surrogate model (emulator) - a fast approximation to the 'true' model. Here we basically construct $\widehat{\text{model}}(\theta)$ and base inferences on a fast, approximate model with nice statistical properties. A key article on the approach is [Kennedy & O'Hagan 2001](https://rss.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/1467-9868.00294). Although this article is about calibrating a deterministic model, we can also construct stochastic surrogate models, e.g. [Binois et al 2018](https://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10618600.2018.1458625) and use this for calibration/inference. The nice thing about the emulator approach is that we can choose to either emulate the likelihood function or construct an emulator for the model directly.